# Dados repetido fastreport

Tags: sql, delphi, fast-reports

Tenho um arquivo .fr3 nele adicionei uma DBXQuery com o codigo a baixo, com o parametro dele utilizar o numero do documento já existente no relatorio que seria <QPag."Documento">
porem no relatorio quando gerado só traz a informação do primeiro documento como faço para ele trazer de todos ?

```
select pc.DESCRICAO
from PLANOCONTA pc
inner join pagar p on pc.CHAVE = p.CHAVEPLANOCTO
WHERE p.DOCUMENTO=:x
```

[Imagem do relatorio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8dcv.png)

Campo adicionado é o DESCR.PLANO de CTA, na imagem ele pegou a descrição do documento 000005 e aplicou no 000002

como faço para ele pesquisar a do 000002 e dos demais que tiver no relatorio ?
o programa é de terceiros trabalho apenas prestando suporte não tenho acesso ao código fonte

Answer (score -1):

Se eu entendi bem, no final esse 'x' indica que ali seria uma variavel certo? E essa variavel diz respeito a um valor passado no codigo no momento de cadastrar o documento do usuario. Esse documento é alocado em uma coluna da tabela 'pagar', o que quebra é você não possuir acesso ao código-fonte acredito eu, porque senão você poderia verificar qual a lógica empregada nessa variável 'x'. Só uma questão, você possui apenas acesso de select nesse banco? De qual SGBD se trata? Oracle, SQL Server, outros? e essa query voce esta gerando para analisar essa questao.

Comment: tenho acesso ao banco de dados, sim X indica que ele vai utilizar um valor que é gerado no relatorio